# Suppose $P(A) = 0.25$, $P(B) = 0.6$, and $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. What is $ P(\overline {A \cup B})$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $P(A) = 0.25$, $P(B) = 0.6$, and $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. What is $ P(\overline {A \cup B})$?

What I think the answer is:

Because $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, which means that EVERY possible event is included in either $\overline A$ or $\overline B$ (because it can't be in both $A$ and $B$). Thus, the union of $\overline A$ and $\overline B$ includes all possible events, and its probability is a certainty (probability equal to $1$).

I want to verify if this is the correct way to answer this question.

Comment: That's now what mutually exclusive means.  Mutually exclusive means that both A and B cannot happen.  More formally $P(A \cap B) = 0)$.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows I think you mean $P(A \cap B) = 0$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks.  That is what I meant.

Comment: Oops.  @Eron23.  I misread what you said.  You're correct mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

By the complement rule, $P(\overline{A \cup B}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$.

By the addition rule for two events, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, by the comments above, you have enough to solve the problem.